# How to move last commits to separate branches in Git

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have a tree that looks like this:

```
--c--c--c--c--c--c--c--c--c1--c2--c3--c4
```

I want to move the last commits to new branches as follow,

```
--c--c--c--c--c--c--c--c
                        \\\--c1--c2
                         \\--c3
                          \--c4
```

How do I move last commits to separate branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout -b branch-3
git cherry-pick c3

git checkout -b branch-4
git cherry-pick c4

git checkout master
git reset --hard c2
```

Comment: The answer is essentially correct, but the first two `checkout` commands need to be more specific: `git checkout -b branch-3 c1^` and `git checkout -b branch-4 c1^`.

Comment: But where is the command when you create the branch for c1--c2 ?

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira please read [Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) from the [**FREE** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira: That's the `reset --hard`, which rewinds to `c2`.   Cupcake is also correct.

Comment: what I understand from the man page for git reset is that it resets the HEAD and with --hard it resets also the working tree, but I'm asking about the command that creates the 3rd branch I don't even see the branch's name there

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira: I thought you wanted to reset `master`.  If you don't, change it to `git checkout -b branch-2 master`

Comment: But then how to move the c1 and c2 to branch-2 ?